# Remove extra font

Tags: 16.04, fonts, internationalization

There is a Chinese font (WenQuanYi Micro Hei) which I'd rather remove since I don't use it and I guess it takes up memory. Where is the file for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the font:

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or find the icon through the dash or menus of your desktop environment).

Then run one of the following commands in a terminal..

```
sudo apt remove fonts-wqy-microhei
```

or

```
sudo apt purge fonts-wqy-microhei
```

Purge also removes any configuration files the package may have.

`sudo` will ask for your password. Note that the password will not echo on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

For removing fonts, they are usually in two different locations in Ubuntu 16.04.

If you have installed it via aptitude (apt/apt-get), it is usually located in: 
`/usr/share/fonts` or sometimes in: `/usr/local/share/fonts` and you can usually remove it by running a command in the terminal. The command is this: `sudo apt-get remove package-name` or `sudo apt remove package-name`. If you would also like to remove all traces of any configuration files for the font, you can use purge instead of remove like this: `sudo apt-get purge package-name` or like this: `sudo apt purge package-name`

However, if you have manually installed a font like I did, you should find it in: `/home/yourusername/.local/share/fonts/` and you can simply just delete the font file there. If you cannot find it there, you could also look in: `/home/yourusername/.fonts/` for it and delete it.

Of course, if all else fails, there is a command you can run to display all your installed fonts and their directory. The command is: `fc-list` and you can pipe grep to it so that you can find your font name. To do this, you would open up terminal and type: `fc-list | grep fontname` and then it should only output the details of font you are looking for including the directory of the font.